# how to handle a long wait time for data, when ios 8+ app has been backgrounded by user

Tags: ios, swift

I've spent a lot of time looking at the options but am still not 100% clear, so wanted to reach out for some guidance.

Scenario is this:

- User submits an `HTTPS` request to our backend server for some data via an iOS app
- Depending on the data, the first (only) request can take a REALLY long time. like, say, 10+ minutes (shocking i know)
- When that payload finally does become available and is returned via the `HTTPS` request, we then want to use it to update the UI in background.

The assumption here is that the user has moved on to another app whilst waiting for the data to arrive (and lets also assume they haven't killed the app).

Is it possible to handle this via iOS 8+ API's without the app being force/killed by Apple when in the background ?

Could we use background task for example?

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier

xxx.beginBackgroundTaskWithName...
```

etc

Before testing some code blocks we just wanted to see if someone has (a) already done this and/or (b) whether we're heading in the right direction

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-think on your web service which may take almost 10 min to process. If you are not able to optimize server task processing time then below one of the idea may be help you.

- You can divided your one request into multiple request to reduce processing time and get response in faster way.
- Your server should sent notification to app when its done with its task. So app will came to know task is done.

I am not sure why you try to update UI when apps in background mode , you may try to update UI when users come to foreground mode from background mode.

Please check [this link](http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/) which show as example of long running task. Where its use a blank audio play to keep alive app background task.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately there is nothing we can do about the server delays for the first load of data. Time to write some tests..

Answer (score 0):

You can used "Background fetch" functionality.
For learning purpose you can refer this [link](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-background-fetch-ios)